# R, replacement length error in loop

Tags: r, dplyr

So i have this loop, where i create a new dataframe while in the loop (this seems to be working fine). I also create a new column in the dataframe so my top 5 values have a 1-5 value attached to them.
The problem seems to be the
 Top5$Rang <- NA

Not when i run the code for each individual value of i, but when i do the loop. And then i get this error:
    Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Rang", value = NA) : 
    replacement has 1 row, data has 0

Can anyone see what im missing?
This is the loop:

```
for (i in Komnr){
    Top <- filter(pendling, Komnr==i) 
    Top5 <- Top %>% top_n(5) 

    write.table(Top5)

    Top5$Rang <- NA
    Top5$Rang <- 1:nrow(Top5)

    write.table(Top5)
}
```

Comment: Probably `Top` has no entries in it, so `Top5` ends up with 0 rows.

Comment: There's probably a nice way to do this without a loop. You just want to save the top 5 rows of each (or some?) value of `Komnr`? How about `pendling %>% group_by(Komnr) %>% top_n(5) %>% do(write.table, <add something for a file name here>)`

Comment: Can you add some data so folks can reproduce this?

Comment: @Gregor Thanks ill try that! However i cant do without the loop - when the code is done it has to be added to a bigger loop where a document is generated for each Komnr value. Do you know if your suggestion is compatible with a loop also? :)

Comment: Oh and @user2554330 it dosent seem to be a problem, the loop only stops when it gets to the new column command. Do you think it deletes the data or something? Ill see if i can post the data set so it can be recreated!

Comment: No, if this is part of a bigger loop than leave it as-is.

Comment: The error is telling you that, in some iteration, when you do `Top5$Rang <- NA`, `Top5` has 0 rows. So it seems like your loop index `for (i in Komnr)` includes values that aren't actually present in the data. Maybe add a `print(i)` before the the problem line and you can identify the problem value. Make sure it's actually in your data.